# How to import multiple pages into Excel from ESPN

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I need to import data from ESPN Fantasy Football into Excel. This includes multiple pages and a web query does not work. The URL is http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?startIndex=0. When you click next, the URL becomes http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?startIndex=40 and 80 and so on. Basically, the startIndex increments to multiples of 40 when you click on the next page.

This is the code I've user so far modifying the code provided by @Dee and it seems to adding a new worksheet but has no data in it.

```
 Private Const URL_TEMPLATE As String = 
"URL;http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?startIndex={0}"
Private Const NUMBER_OF_PAGES As Byte = 7

Sub test()
    Dim page As Byte
    Dim queryTableObject As QueryTable
    Dim url As String

    For page = 1 To NUMBER_OF_PAGES
        url = VBA.Strings.Replace(URL_TEMPLATE, "{0}", page * 40)
        Set queryTableObject = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=url, Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.[a1])
        queryTableObject.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        queryTableObject.WebTables = "14"
        queryTableObject.Refresh
    Next page

End Sub
```

The end result should be pulling all the columns from each page into a tab in one Excel sheet. Is there a way to do this? Please assist.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Thanks Tim. I tried running your code. It added 7 new worksheets with no data in it. Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The `Id` of the table is not `14` but `playertable_0`. If you need to paste all the data to one single sheet try to use the following modified code. `Number of pages` is here determined just by guessing. You will have to add some more code to prove if e.g. the `Next` element is present on the page and do it in do-loop or just simply guess the number of pages. HTH

```
Option Explicit

Private Const URL_TEMPLATE As String = _
 "URL;http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?startIndex={0}"
Private Const NUMBER_OF_PAGES As Byte = 20
Private Const TableId As String = "playertable_0"

Sub test()
    Dim page As Byte
    Dim queryTableObject As QueryTable
    Dim url As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim target As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    Set target = ws.[a1]
    lastRow = 1

    For page = 0 To NUMBER_OF_PAGES
        url = VBA.Strings.Replace(URL_TEMPLATE, "{0}", page * 40)

        Set queryTableObject = ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
            Connection:=url, _
            Destination:=target)

        With queryTableObject
            .BackgroundQuery = False ' Run the query synchronously 
                                     ' to be able to compute the last row
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebTables = TableId
            .Refresh
        End With

        lastRow = ws.Cells.Find( _
            what:="*", _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows) _
            .Row

        Set target = ws.Cells(lastRow + 1, 1)
        target.Select
    Next page
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go. I hope it will fix all the issues you are having.

```
Sub Espn_Data()
    Const URL = "http://games.espn.com/ffl/tools/projections?startIndex="
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, html As New HTMLDocument, page As Long
    Dim htmla As Object, tRow As Object, tCel As Object, ws As Worksheet

    For page = 0 To 120 Step 40  '''input the highest number replacing 120 to get them all
        With http
            .Open "GET", URL & page, False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        With ThisWorkbook
            Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
            ws.Name = page
        End With

        Set htmla = html.getElementsByClassName("playerTableTable tableBody")(0)

        For Each tRow In htmla.Rows
            For Each tCel In tRow.Cells
                c = c + 1: Cells(x + 1, c) = tCel.innerText
            Next tCel
            c = 0
            x = x + 1
        Next tRow
        c = 0
        x = 0
    Next page
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The Web Query for ESPN doesn't work any longer with ESPN Fantasy Football... I don't know why as it only returns all of the page info except what is in the table... Don't insult my intelligence, I've tried all of the settings...
I have come to discover that Excel only allows IE 6 as a web browser as you can find this in the 'File/Options/Advanced/General'  "Web Options" then Browsers and then scroll into Target Browsers.... There are your choices for Web Query to obtain Data.... ESPN does not support any of those browsers so like you, we're screwed until EXCEL updates our choices - Yes, I know... It's 2021 :(